# Java League of Legends ping checker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, networking, benchmarking

I'm still a freshman and this one of my first projects I made using Java and Swing.

The program is a simple League of Legends multi-threaded ping checker that  pings the server 10 times to get an average ping and determine the max and minimum ranges.

How can I make my code cleaner instead of writing so many if statements? Any suggestions or tips are greatly appreciated.

To check your ping you can download the software [here](https://github.com/LeoBogod22/Java-LoL-ping-checker/blob/master/selenium.jar).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
/**
 *
 * @author User
 */
public class App {


    public static void sendPingRequest2(String ipAddress, javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1, javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2, javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1) {

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                long finish = 0;
                long start = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
                System.out.println("Sending Ping Request to " + ipAddress);
                long sum = 0;

                List < Long > list = new ArrayList < > ();



                if (inet.isReachable(5000)) {

                    finish = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();
                    long value = finish - start;

                    list.add(value);
                    long lowest = Collections.min(list);
                    System.out.println("value" + lowest);
                    sum = value + value / 10;
                    if (value < 250) {

                        jTextPane1.setText("Ping RTT: " + value + "ms");
                        jTextPane2.setText("average ping: " + sum + "ms");
                        jTextField1.setText("" + lowest + "ms");
                        jTextPane1.setBackground(Color.green);
                        jTextPane2.setForeground(Color.green);
                        jTextField1.setBackground(Color.green);
                    } else if (value > 250 || value < 500) {

                        jTextPane1.setText("Ping RTT: " + value + "ms");
                        jTextPane2.setText("average ping: " + sum + "ms");
                        jTextField1.setText("" + lowest + "ms");
                        jTextPane1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        jTextPane2.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                        jTextField1.setBackground(Color.yellow);

                    } else {

                        jTextPane1.setText("Ping RTT: " + value + "ms");
                        jTextPane2.setText(" " + sum + "ms");
                        jTextField1.setText("" + lowest + "ms");
                        jTextPane1.setBackground(Color.red);
                        jTextPane2.setBackground(Color.red);
                        jTextField1.setBackground(Color.red);
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println(ipAddress + " NOT reachable.");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App m = new App();
        NewJFrame jf = new NewJFrame();



    }

    void sendPingRequest(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

Gui.java

```
package selenium;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author User



public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     * Creates new form NewJFrame
     */
    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:

        App m = new App();


        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {



            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.141.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();

            t1.start();
        }
        if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {


            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.156.1", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();
        }


        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.142.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }

        if (jRadioButton4.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.136.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }

        if (jRadioButton5.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.131.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }



    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }




    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        App m = new App();


        if (jRadioButton1.isSelected()) {



            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.141.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();

            t1.start();
        }
        if (jRadioButton2.isSelected()) {


            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.156.1", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();
        }


        if (jRadioButton3.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.142.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }

        if (jRadioButton4.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.136.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }

        if (jRadioButton5.isSelected()) {




            Thread t1 = new Thread(new progress(jProgressBar1));
            t1.start();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    m.sendPingRequest2("104.160.131.3", jTextPane1, jTextPane2, jTextField1); // Insert some method call here.
                }



            });

            t2.start();


        }



    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

constants.java

```
public enum Constants {
    NA ("104.160.131.3"), EUW("104.160.141.3"),EUNE("104.160.142.3"),KOR("104.160.156.1"),LAN("104.160.136.3");

    private String ip;

    Constants(String ip){
        this.ip = ip;
    }

    public String getIp(){
        return ip;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this counts as an answer but I think there is strong reason to switch to JavaFX instead of using Swing. [See here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6).

Comment: Also, I haven't used Swing, but it seems part of the reason you should use JavaFX is that it better supports the MVC paradigm. In particular, you can utilize FXML/CSS to design the UI and let the logic be controlled in Java. This isn't particularly in depth since I don't do much Java development, but the general rule of thumb for GUI applications is to *not* write static UIs in Java/C/etc. and use a markup-esque language to do so instead.

Answer (score 2):

In no particular order:

- **Trust the math**. When you test for `value > 250 || value < 500` you already *know* that `value` is greater than 250 (otherwise, the code would go into `if` clause). Testing for `value < 500` suffices.

  BTW, what a background color would be if `value` is exactly 250?
- **DRY #1**. The block of code

  ```
                  jTextPane1.setText("Ping RTT: " + value + "ms");
                  jTextPane2.setText("average ping: " + sum + "ms");
                  jTextField1.setText("" + lowest + "ms");
                  jTextPane1.setBackground(Color.green);
                  jTextPane2.setForeground(Color.green);
                  jTextField1.setBackground(Color.green);
  ```

  is repeated thrice. The only difference is `Color` value. Assign it in the `if`s, and factor the rest out:

  ```
              if (value < 250) {
                  color = Color.green;
              } else if (value < 500) {
                  color = Color.yellow;
              } else {
                  color = Color.red;
              }

              jTextPane1.setText("Ping RTT: " + value + "ms");
              jTextPane2.setText("average ping: " + sum + "ms");
              jTextField1.setText("" + lowest + "ms");
              jTextPane1.setBackground(color);
              jTextPane2.setForeground(color);
              jTextField1.setBackground(color);
  ```
- **DRY #2**. Ditto for `if (jRadioButtonX.isSelected())` cases. The only difference is the IP you are going to ping. Associate the IP with the button, and use the same `actionPerformed` for each of them.

  Speaking of which, why `jRadioButton1.isSelected()` case calls `t1.start()` twice?
- It feels creepy that `jButton1ActionPerformed` creates `new App()`. An `App` should be created once. I am afraid there is a big design problem here.
- **`sum = value + value / 10`** is very much a mistake. Even `sum = sum + value / 10` does not compute the correct average.
- I see reporting the (incorrect) average, and the min time. I don't see reporting *max* time.

Comment: what exactly is the design problem and how can i fix it ? can you please explain in more details? i was trying to call the method when you click the button